# Add disabled class to the html element if the product is already in cart

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using this code to block users to add the same product in the mini cart, it is working fine.

```
//Block to add same product in the mini cart
function check_if_cart_has_product( $valid, $product_id, $quantity ) {  

    if(!empty(WC()->cart->get_cart()) && $valid){
        foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
            $_product = $values['data'];

            if( $product_id == $_product->id ) {
                unset(WC()->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key]);
                echo'<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart disabled"></i>';
            }
        }
    }

    return $valid;

}
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_if_cart_has_product', 10, 3 );
```

But i want here to disabled add to cart button when product is already in the cart and when user remove the product from the cart then make again enable the button.

```
<a href="?add-to-cart=575" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="575" data-product_sku="1234" aria-label="Add &ldquo;Mercedes-Benz rose&rdquo; to your cart" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
```

Can anyone help how can i get this?

Answer (score 0):

If you make it a link, you will need to change the href also along with enable/disable toggle. If you have button, then you can simply use jquery for that.

Comment: I tried to toggle a class via jQuery, but the issue is when reload the page button is again enable and the product remain in the cart.

Comment: You will need to check this on page load as well, and if product is in cart, then add disable class on page load itself

Comment: Can you give me a example please? i have no clue how can i target exact product which in the cart.

Comment: i tried like with this code

 //Delay add disabled class on cart
$('.fa-shopping-cart').on('click',function(){
 var $this = $(this).addClass('finsihed');
 window.setTimeout(function(){
     $this.addClass('disabled-button');
 }, 1500); //<-- Delay in milliseconds
});
But it has no relation with product.

Comment: This is jquery, but when page loads, you can call this function check_if_cart_has_product() before button loads. If its true, then you can disable it on load itself. You can make href="javascript;" and add disable class.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example how can i implement this? Really i did't understand correctly :(